# Android Search with Edit Text in List view does not work properly

Tags: android, list, search, android-edittext

I'm trying to implement an edit text on top of a list view to make searches on my list.

The search with Edit Text is not working very well, some customer names he can think and not others.
  Please help me, below is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private List<Cliente> listaClientes = null;
public ClienteAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Cliente> arraycli   = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    arraycli.add(new Cliente("luis", R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    arraycli.add(new Cliente("aaaaa", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    arraycli.add(new Cliente("bbbb", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    arraycli.add(new Cliente("ccccc", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    arraycli.add(new Cliente("aaaa", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    arraycli.add(new Cliente("testeeeeee", R.drawable.ic_launcher)); 
    final ClienteAdapter adapter = new ClienteAdapter(this, R.id.listView1, arraycli);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);  
    EditText procurar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edprocurar);
    procurar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {     
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString()); 

        }           
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }           
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

}

My Custom Adapter

```
ublic class ClienteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cliente>   {    
 public ArrayList<Cliente> original; 
 public ArrayList<Cliente> fitems;   
 private Filter filter;      

 public ClienteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Cliente> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.original = new ArrayList<Cliente>(items);
        this.fitems = new ArrayList<Cliente>(items);

    } 
private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView ClienteNome;    
    public ImageView ClienteImg;
}

public void addItem(final Cliente item)
{       
    this.original.add(item);
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v  = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
      if (v == null) 
      { 
          LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
          v = vi.inflate(R.layout.clienteitem, null);
          holder = new ViewHolder();
          holder.ClienteNome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.clinome);
          holder.ClienteImg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagem_plista);
          v.setTag(holder);
      }
      else
          holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();        
      final Cliente cliente  = original.get(position);
      if (cliente != null) {
            holder.ClienteNome.setText(cliente.getNomeCliente());               
            holder.ClienteImg.setImageResource(cliente.getImagemCliente());
        }                 
  return v;
}   
public Filter getFilter()
{
     if (filter == null) 
          filter = new ClassClienteFiltro();     
     return filter; 
}   
private class ClassClienteFiltro extends Filter
{
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults(); 
        String prefix = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(); 

         if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) 
         {
             ArrayList<Cliente> list = new ArrayList<Cliente>(original); 
             results.values = list;
             results.count = list.size(); 
         }
         else
         {
             final ArrayList<Cliente> list = new ArrayList<Cliente>(original); 
             final ArrayList<Cliente> nlist = new ArrayList<Cliente>(); 
             int count = list.size();

             for (int i=0; i<count; i++) 
             {
                 final Cliente clienteclass = list.get(i);
                 final String value = clienteclass.getNomeCliente().toLowerCase();

                 if (value.startsWith(prefix)) 
                 {
                     nlist.add(clienteclass); 
                 }
             }
             results.values = nlist; 
             results.count = nlist.size(); 
         }
        return results;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        fitems = (ArrayList<Cliente>)results.values;
         clear(); 
         int count = fitems.size(); 
         for (int i=0; i<count; i++) 
         {
             Cliente cliente = (Cliente)fitems.get(i);
             add(cliente); 
         }  
    }   
}
```

}

I saw many examples in the forum, but unfortunately could not make it work 100%. please help me.
 Already thanks for listening

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in my app, but instead of using the Adapter to do the searching I do the searching logic within the onTextChanged Method.

This can be achieved by creating a secondary ArrayList based on what the user types, then creating a secondary Adapter with the updated information.

Whenever a user types do the folliwng:

A. Clear the Secondary ArrayList.

B. Go through the Primary ArrayList and search for names that match what the user types.

C. Add these items to your Secondary ArrayList.

D. Create a new Adapter with your Secondary ArrayList.

E. Set your ListView's adapter to the new one.

```
    arraycliSort = new ArrayList<Cliente>(); //secondary ArrayList

    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count){                 

            textlength = yourEditText.getText().length();
            arraycliSort.clear(); //A



            for (int i = 0; i < arraycli.size(); i++) { //B
                if (textlength <= arraycli.get(i).name.length()) {
                    if (yourEditText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) arraycli.get(i).name.subSequence(0,textlength)))
                    {
                        arraycliSort.add(arraycli.get(i)); //C
                    }
                }
            }

            adapter = new ClientAdapter(this, R.id.listView1, arraycli); //D
            yourListView.setAdapter(adapter); //E
        }
    });
```

In my example I am not sure how you access the names you are searching for, so I used arraycli.get(i).name, you will have to adjust as necessary.

Hope this can help.